# in excel auto capture date and time with user name when they visit a sheet

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me to wite codes for excel sheet where :
I have an excel sheet which is saved in a shared drive, used by many processors.
There will a sheet for latest updates.
Macro should pop up a question when anyone opens it "If you have gone thru recent updates?"
If user click on YES macro should stop and if user click on NO it should take him/her to sheet named as Updates. Also it should capture date , time and users name from the list whcih will be in a sheet where macro will captrue date and time.

This is needed just to confirm if that perticular processor has visited the updates page or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the worksheet's code section.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If MsgBox("If you have gone thru recent updates?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Updates").Activate
        MsgBox Environ("UserName") & ": " & Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently Stack Overflow *is* a code-writing service.  Also, per Meta, don't ask users to upvote and accept (and not "favorite", as you incorrectly called it) your answers:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271810/is-it-ok-to-ask-to-upvote-accept-my-own-answers